# Two joins between two tables on the same field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a MySQL database V_Activity_SameTimeActivity with two fields SameTimeActivityId and ActivityId. They are both fields which reference the Id field from ACTIVITY_V table. I want to create a view that shows me the ACTIVITY_V.Name field for both sets of Id in the V_Activity_SameTimeActivity table. I can get one but not the other. This the query so far.

```
SELECT
ACTIVITY_V.Name AS MasterActivity,
V_Activity_SameTimeActivity.ActivityId,
V_Activity_SameTimeActivity.SameTimeActivityId

FROM V_Activity_SameTimeActivity
INNER JOIN ACTIVITY_V ON V_Activity_SameTimeActivity.ActivityId = ACTIVITY_V.Id;
```

I also want ACTIVITY_V.Name AS SametimeActivity to show with V_Activity_SameTimeActivity.SameTimeActivityId joined on ACTIVITY_V.Id

Comment: can explain it with example?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

you can join again `ACTIVITY_V`  for your `SameTimeActivityId` mapping

```
SELECT
    t2.Name AS MasterActivity,
    t3.Name AS SameActivityName,
    t1.ActivityId,
    t1.SameTimeActivityId
FROM V_Activity_SameTimeActivity t1
LEFT JOIN ACTIVITY_V t2 ON t1.ActivityId = t2.Id;
LEFT JOIN ACTIVITY_V t3 ON t3.ActivityId = t1.SameTimeActivityId;
```